# Может ли псевдокласс hover показать div, не являющейся дочерним

Tags: html, css

У меня есть два родительских контейнера, я хочу понять, будет ли работать псевдокласс `:hover`, при наведении на любой из трех элементов которые находятся в классе `cl1`, на элемент который находится в классе `cl3`.

Например, навели указатель на `<div class="cl2">Hover1</div>` и должен отобразиться `<div class="cl4">I'm hidden2</div>`.

Вот что у меня получилось, естественно это не работает.

```css
.cl4 {
  display: none;
}

.cl1 ~ .cl2:hover ~ .cl3 ~ .cl4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cl1">
      <div class="cl2">Hover1</div>
      <div class="cl2">Hover2</div>
      <div class="cl2">Hover3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cl3">
      <div class="cl4">I'm hidden1</div>
      <div class="cl4">I'm hidden2</div>
      <div class="cl4">I'm hidden3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: нет, так сделать нельзя.

Comment: нет, так сделать на css нельзя

Comment: То есть без `js` не обойтись?

Comment: Комбинатор '~' выбирает элементы, которые находятся на этом же уровне вложенности, после указанного элемента, с тем же родителем. P.S. там где не справится css пройдет js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае на `css` так сделать нельзя.

Как вариант - использовать псевдокласс [:target](http://htmlbook.ru/css/target)

```css
.cl4 {
  display: none;
}

.cl4:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cl1">
  <a class="cl2" href="#id1">Hover1</a>
  <a class="cl2" href="#id2">Hover2</a>
  <a class="cl2" href="#id3">Hover3</a>
</div>

<div class="cl3">
  <div class="cl4" id="id1">I'm hidden1</div>
  <div class="cl4" id="id2">I'm hidden2</div>
  <div class="cl4" id="id3">I'm hidden3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не знал о псевдоклассе `target`. В этом есть смысл, он решает еще одно мою проблемы, что первый элемент был выбран по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

### Ответ

Нет, при наведении на вложенный элемент (cl2), вы не сможете обратиться к внешнему элементу. Влияние CSS распространяется сверху вниз и не может идти в обратном направлении (вы не можете обратиться через child элемент к родителю).

Вам потребуется JS, если нужно обращаться по DOM дереву вверх. (Показал в примере вариант с Jquery и closest -> find)

Символ `~` позволяет обратиться к соседнему элементу.

В конкретно вашем примере вы можете отлавливать hover на родительском элементе cl1 и по нему обращаться к соседним элементам.

Вы можете на :hover повесить сразу несколько правил и отображать и cl3 и вложенные в него элементы. (показал в примере).

### Посмотрите примеры:

```js
$('.cl10').hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).closest('.container').find('.cl11').show();
    $( this ).closest('.container').find('.cl12').show();
  }, function() {
    $( this ).closest('.container').find('.cl11').hide();
    $( this ).closest('.container').find('.cl12').hide();
  }
);
```

```css
.container{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container > div{
flex:0 0 100%;
}
.cl3 {
  display: none;
}

.cl1:hover~.cl3 {
  display: block;
}

.cl8,
.cl7 {
  display: none;
}

.cl5:hover~.cl7 .cl8 {
  display: block;
}

.cl5:hover~.cl7 {
  display: block;
}


.cl11,
.cl12 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h3>Обращение через CSS к соседнему элементу</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cl1">
      <div class="cl2">отлавливаем hover на cl1</div>
      <div class="cl2">отлавливаем hover на cl1</div>
      <div class="cl2">отлавливаем hover на cl1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cl3">
      <div class="cl4">Показываем cl3 через ~</div>
      <div class="cl4">Показываем cl3 через ~</div>
      <div class="cl4">Показываем cl3 через ~</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Обращение через CSS к соседнему элементу и вложенным в него элементам</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cl5">
      <div class="cl6">отлавливаем hover на cl5</div>
      <div class="cl6">отлавливаем hover на cl5</div>
      <div class="cl6">отлавливаем hover на cl5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cl7">
      <div class="cl8">Показываем cl7 и cl8 через ~ и несколько правил</div>
      <div class="cl8">Показываем cl7 и cl8 через ~ и несколько правил</div>
      <div class="cl8">Показываем cl7 и cl8 через ~ и несколько правил</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3>Обращение через jQuery к родительскому элементу и вложенным в него элементам</h3>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cl9">
      <div class="cl10">отлавливаем hover на cl9</div>
      <div class="cl10">отлавливаем hover на cl9</div>
      <div class="cl10">отлавливаем hover на cl9</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cl11">
      <div class="cl12">Показываем через jQuery cl11 и вложенный в него cl12<div>
      <div class="cl12">Показываем через jQuery cl11 и вложенный в него cl12<div>
      <div class="cl12">Показываем через jQuery cl11 и вложенный в него cl12<div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```